# I can't quick punch-in / how do I start recording audio while playing in logic?

Tags: macos, mojave, logic

I have been pressing space to play the stuff I have already created, and then I hit 'r' to start recording (audio) but it never records anything.

I only seem to be able to record when I am not playing the track previously.

How can I record immediately ?

Answer (score 1):

Logic Pro will start recording when you hit 'r' on the track that is currently selected. If you have a different track selected than the one you need to record to, it will record to that track instead (and if it is a software instrument, no audio will be recorded).

The solution is to have your audio track selected when you are listening to playback.

Comment: I have the correct track selected.